# PostgreSQL AutoVacuum does not work on Table1 during long running transaction on Table2

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, autovacuum

I have two tables: `Table1` and `Table2`. 
 If there is long running query :
 `Select * from Table2;` 
 will it affect AutoVacuum process on `Table1` also?

Comment: No. as long as sufficient cpu/io resources are available on the postgres server.

Comment: Your question seems to answer your comment ? What is your current set up and what information do you have that makes you think the vacuum is not working ?